# Oracle slow join with view

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using the following query to find a monetary transaction for a person.

```sql
SELECT
  PERSON.NAME,
  MONETARY_TRANSACTION.DESCRIPTION
FROM PERSON
LEFT JOIN MONETARY_TRANSACTION
  ON PERSON.ID = MONETARY_TRANSACTION.PERSON_ID
WHERE PERSON.ID = 5
AND ROWNUM <= 1
```

*1.5 min.*

If I run them seperately:

```sql
SELECT NAME FROM PERSON WHERE PERSON.ID = 5 AND ROWNUM <=1;
```

*0.158 sec.*

```sql
SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM MONETARY_TRANSACTION WHERE PERSON_ID = 5 AND ROWNUM <= 1;
```

*5.423 sec.*

I'm guessing it's taking so long because the join happens before the where clause and each join the view gets recalculated (2.8 million people rows).

The view is MONETARY_TRANSACTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say why this is happening without knowing how complex the SQL in the view is, but a few things to try would be:

a. Run an explain plan to conform your diagnosis.

b. Update statistics on the tables being queried.

c. Try using a subquery instead of a left join and see if this hints the optimizer to do what you want. Something like:

```
SELECT
  PERSON.NAME,
  (select MONETARY_TRANSACTION.DESCRIPTION from MONETARY_TRANSACTION where PERSON.ID = MONETARY_TRANSACTION.PERSON_ID)
FROM PERSON
WHERE PERSON.ID = 5
AND ROWNUM <= 1
```

d. Try using limit 1 instead of the rownum comparison. I believe Oracle supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving
PERSON.ID = 5
out of the Where clause and into the Join clause. It might filter rows out sooner.

Also, try replacing ROWNUM = 1 with a FETCH FIRST clause. But I think that only works on Oracle 12c or newer.

Comment: please edit answer and add full answer of query like question query... for give best feedback, you can read about this in help center : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer